# How to calculate this Stieltjes integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

Given that f is a continuous function and [x] is the biggest integer which is smaller than x, 
I want to integrate f(x)d[x] from 0 to n, where n is a natural number.
I know the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral,
 but I can't actually use the definition to calculate the examples...

Comment: Isn't this just $f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)$?

Comment: MPW is correct. In a bit more detail, $[x]$ changes exactly at the integers. At each integer it jumps up by $1$. So an integral over an interval with respect to $[x]$ is a sum of the values of the integrand at the integers contained in the interval, each multiplied by the jump amount (i.e. by $1$).